# Adjective upper or lower cased after article, if it already describes a noun?

Tags: adjective

do I write *gerechtes* in this specific case upper or lower-cased:

*das Handeln ist ein Gerechtes / gerechtes*

I'm asking, because you normally write an adjective upper-cased if there is an article before it, but otherwise it describes a noun and should be lower-cased

I am pleased about any constructive answer! But if possible say **why** it's written like that :)

Comment: I tend to lower case because "gerechtes" describes Handeln. You could extend the sentence to "Das Handeln ist ein gerechtes Handeln.". (I don't write a proper answer because I don't have any rules/sources.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be lower cased. The applicable [rule in Duden is](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D73):

> Wenn nach einem Adjektiv ein Substantiv eingespart worden ist, das sonst noch im Kontext vorkommt und daher ohne Weiteres ergänzt werden kann, schreibt man klein (= attributiv-elliptischer Gebrauch) <§ 58 (1)>.
>
> ZUM BEISPIEL
>
> - Mir gefallen alle Krawatten sehr gut. Besonders mag ich die gestreiften und die gepunkteten (= die gestreiften und gepunkteten Krawatten).
> - Sie war die aufmerksamste und klügste unter allen Zuhörerinnen.
> - Das blaue ist mein Auto.

In your example, the context makes it clear that you want to say "das Handeln ist ein gerechtes Handeln". This constitutes an "attributiv-elliptischer Gebrauch".